# OWLAPI find all DataSomeValuesFrom of a specific class

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

This is a part of my OWL File:

```
# Class: :Book (:Book)

SubClassOf(:Book ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:writtenBy owl:Thing))
SubClassOf(:Book DataSomeValuesFrom(:genre rdfs:Literal))
SubClassOf(:Book DataSomeValuesFrom(:title rdfs:Literal))
```

How can i get only the `DataSomeValuesFrom` attributes? 
i'm using owlapi 5.1.0
and Hermit as reasoner.

EDIT: This is how i solved. I don't know if this is the right method but it works.

Thanks to @AKSV for answer me with very useful information....

```
          for (OWLClass cls : o.getClassesInSignature()){
            Set<OWLSubClassOfAxiom> set = o.getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass(cls);
            for(OWLSubClassOfAxiom subcl : set){
                OWLClassExpression nomeattribEXPR = subcl.getSuperClass();
                if(nomeattribEXPR.getClassExpressionType().toString().equals("DataSomeValuesFrom")){
                   //do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: aha, and where is the code you tried so far? load the ontology, get all subclass axioms, and then check for those with superclass being of type [`OWLDataSomeValuesFrom`](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataSomeValuesFrom.html)

Comment: I don't understand the "aha". Anyway i posted the question because i don't know how to use very well OWLAPI and all i ask is a short snippet with a short explanation.

Comment: Your solution works indeed. A minor improvement, you can use a "better" comparison of the class expression type by using [the enum](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/ClassExpressionType.html#DATA_SOME_VALUES_FROM), i.e.  `nomeattribEXPR.getClassExpressionType() == ClassExpressionType.DATA_SOME_VALUES_FROM`

Answer (score 0):

Use a visitor for best effect (no need to check strings for types):

```
      // this is OWLAPI 5; for OWLAPI 4, use OWLObjectVisitorAdapter
      OWLObjectVisitor v=new OWLObjectVisitor(){
          public void visit(OWLSubClassOfAxiom ax) {
              ax.getSuperClass().accept(this);
          }
          public void visit(OWLDataSomeValuesFrom c){
              //do something
          }
      };
      for (OWLClass cls : o.getClassesInSignature()){
        o.getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass(cls).forEach(ax->ax.accept(v));
      }
```